# Is there a way to add a suffix to a pod's name when using the kubectl scale command

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I'm running a command like this:

```
# add an executor pod
kubectl scale deployments executor --replicas 1

# show new pod
kubectl get pods
# NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
# executor-8cb7dc8689-w58ls           1/1     Running   0        11m
```

This is typically done to to run some command via `kubectl exec`.

We have multiple people on the team occasionally doing this and sometimes forgetting to scale back down, leaving these resources up.

Is there a way I can dynamically add a suffix just to the new pod's name when scaling so I can have some indication of ownership?  For example, something like this:

```
echo $USER
# myusername
kubectl scale deployments executor --replicas 1 --name-suffix $USER

kubectl get pods
# NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
# executor-8cb7dc8689-w58ls-myusername           1/1     Running   0        11m
```

Comment: You may use a `mutating` webhook for the verb `scale` of `resource` type deployment. Although you cannot put prefixes, you can `annotate` the pods. so based on the annotation you can filter,

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. The name of pods are given by the ReplicaSet and it's always `{replicasetname}-{random}`.

I think the best option to achieve something similar is to create one deployment per user and then use RBAC to restrict access to each deployment so that only user1 can scale deployment1, user2 can scale deployment2, etc.